# ImageView keeps scaling the image, making the app lag

Tags: android, imageview, lag

I've got an imageview, that has an image set to display, the imageview is set to match parent in both width and height, however when the fragment containing the image is visible the entire app lags, as it seems to rescale  the image on every redraw, on older devices there are logs that the image can't be scaled over 2048x2048, but I am since recently unable to reproduce this error.

Is there any way to solve this? I've tried creating a custom image viewthat would only need to scale the image once, but upon multiple uses it causes OutOfMemoryException, so I'd prefer the solution with the plain ImageView.

## The regular imageview is used like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>
```

## The alternative with custom imageview:

```
<com.app.myapp.ScaledImageView
        android:id="@+id/scaledImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

## The class:

```
public class ScaledImageView extends View
{
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public ScaledImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScaledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setImageResource(int resId)
    {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), resId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (bitmap != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        try
        {
            Bitmap tmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, false);
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = tmp;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        bitmap = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: with 'mutliple uses' you mean that reusing the same component and image brings the error, or that you show several images at the same time?

Comment: Please add some code for imageview

Comment: there is only one imageview per fragment, but transitioning to and from that fragment after somewhat 30+ uses throws the OutOfMemoryException

Comment: @korunos added code.

Comment: so your problem is, that the image is a big too huge, so that you get a OOM exception?

Comment: the image is 1024x680, I don't think it should throw the OOM exception

Comment: Why **it seems to rescale the image on every redraw**?

Comment: the log I was gettin on the older device was written about 30 times per second, also when using my custom view, that only scales the image once the lag is gone.

Comment: so your problem solved?

Comment: no, both solutions have an issue, the default imageview causes lag, while the custom view causes OOM exception, if used multiple times.

Comment: I would recomment to use the Universal Image Loader which keeps a function for using cache, so multiple uses of images aren't a problem any more. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. It's easy to configure too. please tell me if it helped you solve the problem